# Angular Material 2 Grid Layout Not Working

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to layout my form page using a grid based layout in Angular Material 2 and it is not working.  What tags should be used?

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">    
      <div class="mdl-grid">
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col-phone mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--6-col-desktop">
          <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput placeholder="Project" value="Personal">
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col-phone mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--6-col-desktop">
          <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput placeholder="To Do" value="Buy Bread">
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-grid">
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col-phone mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--6-col-desktop">
          <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput placeholder="Due Date" type="Date">
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col-phone  mdl-cell--4-col-tablet">
          <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput placeholder="Priority" type="number" value="1">
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-grid">
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col-phone mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--6-col-desktop">
          <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput placeholder="Tags" value="grocery">
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col-phone mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--6-col-desktop">
          <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput placeholder="Description" value="We are all out of bread!  This is an emergency!">
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
      </div>      
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working' ? CSS not applying ? Or is the Grid not working as it should ?

Comment: Everything is all in one column regardless of the width of the browser.  And the one column is not the width of the browser.  These tags do not work either from the Angular 1 Material:  https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction

Comment: It seems to work in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n1nne60h/1/ . Do you, by any chance use angular-cli ?

Comment: @YounesM Thanks for your help.  I am using Angular CLI.  That fiddle looks like it is using the theme for version 1.3 instead of 2.x.  Is there a CDN for 2.x?

Comment: I can't seem to find it. But you can still use 3rd party librairies if you include them in your angular-cli.json file under `styles:[ ]`

Comment: I have created a plunker with the Material 2 template and submitted an issue to the Material 2 team.  Plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/hGjpBk?p=info  Github Issue:  https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3801